# How to retrieve unencrypted password from the azure app service connection string

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am new to azure .

I have got a new website to work on its hosted on azure, I needed to find out the connection string .so that i can connect to the database in sql server.

The connection string is something like this

"Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Data Source=------------;Password=XIPG7UYJBOYS----------".

The password given is encrypted i guess . I am unable to login with it.

Is there any way to retrieve the plain password.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The password should not be encrypted and you should include it in the Azure Web App's configuration section. There is a section there for connection strings.

If you need to store it in more secure place then you should use Azure Key Vault

Comment: Hi @Haitham thankyou for your response, But I don't need to store it secure, It is already secured. I needed to get retrieve the plain password. SO that I can take the backup of the db .

Comment: You can't use the password in the connection string for backup and if you can this means the user used in connection string have more permissions than it needs. You should ask the DB Admin to back it up or directly from Azure Portal, Go to the db blade and use the copy feature, this will create a back up of the database

Comment: Thankyou @Haitham, This will help me in getting the backup